# how can i give curl effect to my activity?

Tags: android, animation, page-curl

i have designed an form in that form contain button when i click on the button next page should display in next page also an activity. my requirement is I want to implement page curl animation on button click. 
    I also got page curl animation code from github https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl , but still am confused with how to implement this project as  in my application. can u please tell me how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [android_page_curl](http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fmystictreegames%2Fpagecurl%253Fstate%253Dclosed). This is easy to implement and and have examples for easy understanding.

Comment: thank you for your response. i'm also having the same code but that code was the page curl effect will runs with mouse drag. but i dont need that way I want to implement page curl animation on button click(i want curl effect only when i click the button not entire page click)